# Close Boostrap Offcanvas Sidebar menu by clicking outside of it?

Tags: css, menu

*Hello, friends!

I'm trying to modify Boostrap Offcanvas Template for my site.

The working example is here:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

It works perfect for me and the only thing I'd like to add is closing the sidebar menu by tapping/clicking outside of it (now it works only by clicking toggle button).

If I understand it right, a couple of lines in CSS whould help. My idea is: to (maybe) add some div **which covers the main content** and have *data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#sidebar"* when sidebar menu is active.

I would appreciate your help cause I really can't find the solution.

html

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
          </p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
                      </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>

          </div>
        </div><!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
      </div><!--/row-->
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-right {
right: 0;
  }


  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -50%; /* 6 columns */
  }


  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 50%; /* 6 columns */
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%; /* 6 columns */
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```